# What is the "eval" command in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, eval

What can you do with the `eval` command? Why is it useful? Is it some kind of a built-in function in bash? There is no `man` page for it..

Comment: Use `type command` to learn of what type a *command* is. (`type eval` in ths case)

Comment: "eval is a shell builtin"

Comment: `help eval` to get "man" page from your shell

Comment: eval is a bash-builtin and is documented in the man page of bash. So just type "man bash" and search for the appropriate section for eval. This applies for other bash-builtins, too.

Comment: @m-ric `help eval
zsh: command not found: help` doesn't work?

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72522412/what-does-eval-opam-env-do-does-it-activate-a-opam-environment?noredirect=1&lq=1 for doing the common `eval $(opam env)`.

Comment: The use of shell eval *usually* creates  opportunities for exploits.   It's use should be carefully design & restricted. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220/why-should-eval-be-avoided-in-bash-and-what-should-i-use-instead

Answer (score 244, accepted):

`eval` is part of POSIX. It's an interface which can be a shell built-in.

It's described in the "POSIX Programmer's Manual": http://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1posix/eval/

```
eval - construct command by concatenating arguments
```

It will take an argument and construct a command of it, which will then be executed by the shell. This is the example from the manpage:

```
foo=10 x=foo    # 1
y='$'$x         # 2
echo $y         # 3
$foo
eval y='$'$x    # 5
echo $y         # 6
10
```

1. In the first line you define `$foo` with the value `'10'` and `$x` with the value `'foo'`.
2. Now define `$y`, which consists of the string `'$foo'`. The dollar sign must be escaped
   with `'$'`.
3. To check the result, `echo $y`.
4. The result of 1)-3) will be the string `'$foo'`
5. Now we repeat the assignment with `eval`. It will first evaluate `$x` to the string `'foo'`. Now we have the statement `y=$foo` which will get evaluated to `y=10`.
6. The result of `echo $y` is now the value `'10'`.

This is a common function in many languages, e.g. Perl and JavaScript.
Have a look at perldoc eval for more examples: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html

Comment: In shell terminology, `eval` is a built-in, not a function. In practice, built-ins behave a lot like functions that don't have an in-language definition, but not quite (as becomes apparent if you are twisted enough to define a function called `eval`).

Comment: thx, fixed that :-)

Comment: What is the difference between eval and backticks `  ?

Comment: Backticks are shorthand for executing another entire shell, meaning you'll have another child bash/sh process running within your script.

Comment: Why echo $y (stage 3) brings back foo(10) instead of $foo ? (i.e just the value of foo instead of the string $ + the value of foo) ?

Comment: @Benia Because `$y` is defined right above it as a literal `$` followed by the value of `$x` which exands to `foo`.

Answer (score 94):

Yes, `eval` is a bash internal command so it is described in `bash` man page.

```
eval [arg ...]
    The  args  are read and concatenated together into a single com-
    mand.  This command is then read and executed by the shell,  and
    its  exit status is returned as the value of eval.  If there are
    no args, or only null arguments, eval returns 0.
```

Usually it is used in combination with a [*Command Substitution*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution). Without an explicit `eval`, the shell tries to *execute* the result of a command substitution, not to *evaluate* it.

Say that you want to code an equivalent of `VAR=value; echo $VAR`. Note the difference in how the shell handles the writings of `echo VAR=value`:

1.

```
    andcoz@...:~> $( echo VAR=value )
    bash: VAR=value: command not found
    andcoz@...:~> echo $VAR
    <empty line>
```

The subshell executes the `echo` command and then command substitutes the result, `VAR=value`, back to the outer shell where it throws the error because "VAR=value" is not a command. The assignment remains ineffective because it was never executed, only `echo`ed.

2.

```
    andcoz@...:~> eval $( echo VAR=value )
    andcoz@...:~> echo $VAR
    value
```

The subshell `echo`es "VAR=value" which is again command substituted back to the outer shell where it is then `eval`ed.

Last but not least, `eval` can be a very dangerous command. Any input to an `eval` command must be carefully checked to avoid security problems.

Comment: very nice answer

Comment: Perhaps when you say `Without an explicit eval, the shell tries to execute the result of a command substitution, not to evaluate it.` In your answer you should explain what the difference is between those two with a definition before going to a lengthy example? Ok, will try to go through it to write such an answer.

Comment: this seems like a good answer. Will go through it. Another common example I've seen is `eval $(opam env)` e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72522412/what-does-eval-opam-env-do-does-it-activate-a-opam-environment/72537901#72537901

Comment: when you talk about a "subshell" what are you referring to?

Comment: what confuses me is that `$(echo Var=value)` that `$(...)` does is "allows a command to be run and its output to be pasted back on the command line as arguments to another command." So to me the output of `$(...)` should have been given to the terminal as I typed it to the terminal i.e. `Var=val` which does let me run it. Instead I don't know to what function it's been given that interprets the output of `$(...)` as commands to be ran. Very confusing to me. **tldr: what is the function receiving the output of $(...) and what is the string output of $(...)**?

Answer (score 36):

The eval statement tells the shell to take eval’s arguments as command and run them through the command-line. It is useful in a situation like below:

In your script if you are defining a command into a variable and later on you want to use that command then you should use eval:

```
/home/user1 > a="ls | more"
/home/user1 > $a
bash: command not found: ls | more
/home/user1 > # Above command didn't work as ls tried to list file with name pipe (|) and more. But these files are not there
/home/user1 > eval $a
file.txt
mailids
remote_cmd.sh
sample.txt
tmp
/home/user1 >
```

Comment: The comment in line 4 of your example is wrong: It should be "Above command didn't work because bash tried to find a command called `ls | more`. In other words: The single command name consisted of nine characters, including the spaces and the pipe symbol.

Comment: I get exactly the same behavior he reported. bash --version == GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18)

Answer (score 34):

### What is eval?

eval is a shell command which is usually implemented as a builtin.

In POSIX it is listed as part [of "2.14. Special Built-In Utilities"](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_14) at the entry ["eval"](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_19).
What builtin means is:

> The term "built-in" implies that the shell can execute the utility directly and does not need to search for it.

### What does it do?

In simple terms: makes an input line to be parsed **twice**.

### How does it do that?

The shell has a sequence of steps that it follows to "process" a line. 
You could [look at this image](http://helios.cs.ifmo.ru/~ad/Documentation/Bash_Shell/bash3-CHP-7-SECT-3.html) and realize that eval is the only line that goes up, back to step 1, on the left. 
From [the POSIX description](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html):

> 2.1 Shell Introduction
>
> 1. The shell reads its input ....
> 2. The shell breaks the input into tokens: words and operators
> 3. The shell parses the input into simple and compound commands.
> 4. The shell performs various expansions (separately) ...
> 5. The shell performs redirection and removes redirection operators and their operands from the parameter list.
> 6. The shell executes a function, built-in, executable file, or script ...
> 7. The shell optionally waits for the command to complete and collects the exit status.

At step 6 a built-in will be executed.
At step 6 eval causes the processed line to be sent back to step 1.
It is the only condition under which the execution sequence goes back.

> *That is why I say: With eval an input line is parsed **twice**.*

### Effects of parsing twice.

#### The first.

And most important effect to understand. Is that one consequence of the first time a line is subject to the seven shell steps shown above, is **quoting**. Inside step 4 (expansions), there is also a  [sequence of steps to perform all expansions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06), the last of which is **Quote Removal**:

> Quote removal shall always be performed last.

So, always, there is one level of quoting removed.

#### Second.

As consequence of that first effect, additional/different parts of the line become exposed to the shell parsing and all the other steps.

### Example.

#### Indirection.

That allows to execute indirect expansions:

```sh
a=b b=c    ;    eval echo \$$a            ### shall produce "c"
```

Why?
Because on the first loop, the first `$` is quoted.
As such, it is ignored for expansions by the shell.
The next `$` with the name a is expanded to produce "b".
Then, one level of quoting is removed, making the first `$` unquoted.
End of first loop.

It is then, on the second loop that the string `$b` is read by the shell.
Then expanded to "c"
And given as an argument to `echo`.

To "see" what eval will produce on the first loop (to be evaluated again), use echo. Or any command/script/program that clearly shows the arguments:

```sh
$ a=b b=c
$ eval echo \$$a;
c
```

Replace eval by echo to "see" what is happening:

```sh
$ echo echo \$$a
echo $b
```

It is also possible to show all the "parts" of a line with:

```sh
$ printf '<%s> ' echo \$$a
<echo> <$b>
```

Which, in this example, is only one echo and one variable, but remember it to help in evaluating more complex cases.

#### A correction.

It must be said that: there is a mistake in the code above, can you see it?.
Easy: there are some quotes missing.

How? you may ask. Simple, let's change the variables (not the code):

```sh
$ a=b b="hi     jk"
$ eval echo \$$a
hi jk
```

See the missing spaces?
That is because the value inside `$b` was split by the shell.

If that does not convince you, try this:

```sh
$ a=b b="hi  *  jk"
$ eval echo \$$a              ### warning this will expand to the list  
                              ### of all files in the present directory.
```

#### Why?

Missing quotes. To make it work correctly (add internal `"$a"`and external `\"` quotes).
Try this (is perfectly safe):

```sh
$ a=b b="hi      *       jk"
$ eval echo \" \$"$a" \"
hi      *       jk
```

### About the manual:

> There is no man page for it..

No, there is not an independent man page for this.
The search for manual with `man -f eval` or even `apropos eval` show no entry.

It is included inside `man bash`. As is any built-in.
Search for "SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS" and then for "eval".

An easier way to get help is:
In bash, you could do `help eval` to see the help for the built-in.

## Why is eval called evil?

Because it is binding text to code dynamically.

In other words: it converts the list of its arguments (and/or expansions of such arguments) into an executed line. If for any reason, an argument has been set by an attacker, you will be executing attacker code.

Or even simpler, with eval you are telling whoever defined the value of one or several arguments:

> *C'mon, sit here and type any command line, I will execute it with my powers.*

Is that dangerous? Should be clear for everyone that it is.

The safety rule for eval should be:
   Only execute eval on variables to which **you** have given it's value.

Read [more detail here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048).

Comment: the only really usefull explanation

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I have a question on the term you used: "quoted". On the first example I see the `$` being **escaped**, not quoted. Is escaped characters the same as quoted with single quotes (except for the few escapes allowed inside single quoted text)? Does the documentation refer to escaped text as quoted text? If that's the case I'll want to re-read it to make things clearer in my head.

Comment: This link is broken: `You could [look at this image](http://helios.cs.ifmo.ru/~ad/Documentation/Bash_Shell/bash3-CHP-7-SECT-3.html) and realize...`

Comment: V. good & thorough answer, but: I found this answer trying to understand this one-liner: `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"`. As I understand it, `ssh-agent` must be running in the background to support `ssh-add` & other key ops. Unfortunately, I still don't understand this :/

Answer (score 24):

`eval` has no man page because it is not a separate external command, but rather a shell built-in, meaning a command internal to and known only by the shell (`bash`).  The relevant part of the `bash` man page says:

```
eval [arg ...]
    The args are read and concatenated together into a single command.  
    This command is then  read  and executed by the shell, and its exit 
    status is returned as the value of eval.  If there are no args, or only 
    null arguments, eval returns 0
```

In addition, the output if `help eval` is:

```
eval: eval [arg ...]
    Execute arguments as a shell command.

    Combine ARGs into a single string, use the result as input to the shell,
    and execute the resulting commands.

    Exit Status:
    Returns exit status of command or success if command is null.
```

`eval` is a powerful command and if you intend to use it you should be very careful to head off the possible [security risks](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) that come with it.

Answer (score 17):

`eval` is a feature of most interpreted languages (`TCL`, `python`, `ruby`...), not only shells. It's used to evaluate code dynamically.

In shells, it's implemented as a shell builtin command.

Basically, `eval` takes a string as argument and evaluates/interprets the code in it. In shells, `eval` can take more than one argument, but `eval` just concatenates those to form the string to evaluate.

It's very powerful because you can construct code dynamically and run it, something you can't do in compiled languages like C.

Like:

```
varname=$1 varvalue=$2
eval "$varname=\$varvalue" # evaluate a string like "foo=$varvalue"
                           # which in Bourne-like shell language
                           # is a variable assignment.
```

But it's also dangerous as it's important to sanitize the dynamic (externally provided) parts of what is passed to `eval` for the very reason it's interpreted as shell code.

For instance, above if `$1` is `evil-command; var`, `eval` would end-up evaluating the `evil-command; var=$varvalue` shell code and then run that `evil-command`.

The evilness of `eval` is often over-exaggerated.

OK, it's dangerous, but at least we know it's dangerous.

A lot of other commands will evaluate shell code in its arguments if not sanitized, like (depending on the shell), `[` aka `test`, `export`, `printf`, GNU `sed`, `awk`, and of course `sh`/`bash`/`perl` and all interpreters...

Examples (here using `uname` as the `evil-command` and `$a` as externally provided unsanitized data):

```
$ a='$(uname>&2)' sh -c 'eval "echo $a"'
Linux

$ a='x[0$(uname>&2)]' mksh -c 'export "$a=$b"'
Linux
$ a='x[0$(uname>&2)]' ksh93 -c 'printf "%d\n" "$a"'
Linux
0
$ a='x[0$(uname>&2)]' ksh93 -c '[ "$a" -gt 0 ]'
Linux
$ a=$'bar/g;e uname>&2\n;s//'; echo foo | sed "s/foo/$a/g"
Linux
bar
$ a='";system("uname");"'; awk "BEGIN{print \"$a\"}"

Linux
$ a=';uname'; sh -c "echo $a"

Linux
```

Those `sed`, `export`... commands could be considered more dangerous because while it's obvious `eval "$var"` will cause the content of `$var` to be evaluated as shell code, it's not so obvious with `sed "s/foo/$var/"` or `export "$var=value"` or `[ "$var" -gt 0 ]`. The dangerosity is the same, but it's concealed in those other commands.

Comment: @BinaryZebra, `sed` like `eval` is being passed a string contained in a variable, and for both, the content of that string ends up being evaluated as shell code, so `sed` is as dangerous as `eval`, that's what I'm saying. `sed` is being passed a string containing `uname` (uname has not been executed so far) and through the invocation of `sed`, the uname command ends up being executed. Like for eval. In `sed 's/foo/$a/g'`, you're not passing unsanitized data to `sed`, that's not what we're talking about here.

Comment: Great answer, really clarifies it for me. We can use `eval` to dynamically assign both values and variable names!

Answer (score 16):

This example may shed some light:

```
#!/bin/bash
VAR1=25
VAR2='$VAR1'
VAR3='$VAR2'
echo "$VAR3"
eval echo "$VAR3"
eval eval echo "$VAR3"
```

Output of the script above:

```
$VAR2
$VAR1
25
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, but, as entertaining as they are, we aren’t really interested in compiling a list of (slightly different) examples of using ``eval``. Do you believe that there is some fundamental, critical aspect of the functionality of ``eval`` that isn’t covered in the existing answers? If so, then *explain* it, and use the example to illustrate your explanation.  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: This example may be confusing because not everyone understands the difference between single and double quotes in bash. Put all those variables in double quotes and it will bring a different result.

Answer (score 2):

My experience with `eval` it can convert string output of command to variable , this example from [another question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/192021/93809)

```
eval $(ffprobe -v error -of flat=s=_ -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=height,width ${FILE})
```

when I type it directly to the terminal, I got

```
streams_stream_0_width=1280
streams_stream_0_height=720
```

That stored each one into a new variable to use it inside the script.

```
IN_WIDTH=${streams_stream_0_width}
```

This could be useful to benefit, from another command output, before processing the main command (*e.g get file properties or remote server status* )

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to the party on this but this little example from my console output shows the behaviour of eval versus running a script. It shows that eval evaluates a string *(be it from a file or variable)* and runs the command in the current shell it's in, compared to running a script, which runs in its own shell and exits back to the current shell.
(but also to run a script in the current shell environment, you can just place a dot and a space before the shell script filename)

```
$ pwd
/home/user1

$ cat myscript.sh
cd Desktop

$ ./myscript.sh

$ pwd
/home/user1

$ eval $(cat myscript.sh)

$ pwd
/home/user1/Desktop
```

Comment: You probably need to quote the expansion of the command substitution. Test it with a directory that has space in its name (the script would do `cd "My dir"`).

Answer (score 1):

The `eval` function/macro evaluates Shell code represented as a string and returns its completion value.

The source is parsed as a bash shell.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, `eval` takes all the arguments provided to it, combines them into a single command, and then executes that command.

```bash
command_part1="ls"
command_part2="-l"
eval "$command_part1 $command_part2"
```

is the same as

```bash
ls -l
```