# bash + how to define array variable with instance number

Tags: linux, shell-script, array, variable-substitution

Is it possible to define variable that is called for example machine1 as machine$counter ( while counter=1 ) ?

For example, I created the `/tmp/config.txt` file and set the machine1 as array:

```
 $ more /tmp/config.txt
 machine1=( linux_server critical 1.1.1.1 )
 machine2=( linux_server critical 1.1.1.2 )
 .
 .
```

Then I created the following simple script to read the `/tmp/config.txt`. And I try to print the machine array as the following:

```
 $ more read.config.bash
 #!/bin/bash

 source /tmp/config.txt
 counter=1
 echo ${machine$counter[0]}
 echo ${machine$counter[1]}
 echo ${machine$counter[2]}
 .
 .
```

But when I run the script, I get:

```
$ ./read.config.bash
./read.config.bash: line 6: ${machine$counter[0]}: bad substitution
./read.config.bash: line 7: ${machine$counter[1]}: bad substitution
./read.config.bash: line 8: ${machine$counter[2]}: bad substitution
```

What is the solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `eval` command.

```
eval "echo \${machine${counter[0]}}"
```

Notice that the first `$` is escaped so that it isn't evaluated until `eval` processes the string.

The way this works is that `eval` executes a command the same as if you had typed it at the command prompt.  The difference is that the command that is executed can be constructed programmatically.

So in your scenario, when `eval` runs on the command, the command it is *actually* executing looks like this: `echo ${machineBLAH}`.  The inner variable substitution has already been performed separately by the shell *before* `eval` runs.

For more information, see this other post: [What is the "eval" command in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/23111/83381).

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid to use `eval`

```
source /tmp/config.txt
counter=1
line0="machine$counter[0]"
echo ${!line}
```

And much better to call `echo` via loop

```
for counter in 1 2 3
do
    line="machine$counter[@]"
    for element in "${!line}"
    do
        echo $element
    done
done
```

Comment: This works only in bash. In my testing, this didn't work in zsh, ksh, or tcsh. It's still good to know, though.