# unescape pipe in parameters

Tags: shell-script, pipe, escape-characters

I want to write a bash script that takes in two parameters, running them as commands and dump their output into files. `myscript.sh` contents:

```
$1 > file1.tmp
$2 > file2.tmp
```

This works fine for the following example:

```
myscript.sh 'echo Hello World' 'echo Hello World 2'
```

`file1.tmp` now contains the text `Hello World` and `file2.tmp` contains text `Hello World  2`

However this breaks down when using a command that contains a pipe:

```
myscript.sh 'ls | grep stuff' 'ls | grep morestuff'

ls: cannot access |: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access grep: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access stuff: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access |: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access grep: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access morestuff: No such file or directory
```

It appears the pipe is being escaped because I get similar output as the first error if I for example run this:

```
ls \|

ls: cannot access |: No such file or directory
```

How can I unescape the pipe in my script?

Comment: You would have to `eval "$1" >file1.tmp` etc., but I'm sure there's a better way of achieving what you want to do. Why do you need to pass in shell commands to a script to begin with?

Comment: @Kusalananda I actually don't need to - the script was just an example to describe the behavior that I didn't understand. A [description of eval](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23111/what-is-the-eval-command-in-bash) clarifies why - the goal attempting to be achieved in the script requires the strings to be parsed twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing a piece of shell code into the script. To the script, this is just text. For it to be interpreted as a full-blown shell command, you will have to `eval` it:

```
eval "$1" >file1.tmp
eval "$2" >file2.tmp
```

This works when `$1` and `$2` are simple things like `echo hello` because they are *simple commands* (not lists or compound commands).

An analogy with another programming language would be if you passed a piece of C code into a C program as a text string. The code would have to be compiled (and linked) somehow before it could be executed as part of the program.