# How to run string with values as a command in bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script, command, string

Here is my small bash script snippet.

```
i=5
command='echo $i'
$command
```

I want this script to print `5` i.e., I want it to run echo and print 5. But it instead keeps printing `$i`. So how do I go about solving this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the "eval" command in bash?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23111/what-is-the-eval-command-in-bash)

Comment: I voted to leave this open because the duplicate question is much broader while the advice to use a function in Stéphane's answer (upvoted) is appropriate for this specific question.

Comment: In your case it is probably simpler to define your command as alias, eg.  alias mycommand='echo $i' and then simply type mycommand.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

That would be:

```
eval "$command"
```

If you want the content of `$command` to be evaluated as shell code.

If you can't guarantee that `$command` won't start with `-` (which would cause `eval` in some shells like `bash` to treat it as an option), you may want to run:

```
eval " $command"
```

instead. That extra leading space won't affect the way the command is parsed and will prevent `$command` from being treated as an option to `eval` if it starts with `-`. `eval -- "$command"` would also work in some shells (including `bash`) but is not POSIX (IIRC) and wouldn't work in `dash` or the Bourne shell for instance.

Note that your `$command` should probably be:

```
command='echo "$i"'
```

Unless you did intend `$i` to be subject to split+glob

A potentially better way to store code in "variables" would be to use functions:

```
mycommand() { echo "$i"; }
```

(using `mycommand` instead of `command`, as `command` is already an existing command).

If `$command` is `break`/`continue`/`return`, behaviour will vary depending on the shell.

If you wanted `$command` to store a *simple command*, that is a list of words the first of which is looked up as the command to execute with the list of words as arguments, you'd use an array variable:

```
command=('echo' '$i' "$i")
"${command[@]}"
```

That would run `echo`, with `echo`, `$i` and the content of `$i` as arguments.

```
command='echo $i ;x /* '$i
$command
```

(with the default value of `$IFS`) is the one that would make littlest sense.   There, `$command` would contain a string. The first `$i` left as is, the second expanded (as outside the single quotes), and then that string would be subject to split+glob (as `$command` is not inside double quotes), the outcome of which would result in a number of words, taken as a *simple command* again.

Comment: Wow thanks. I knew it was eval, but I was missing double quotes.

Comment: Im guessing because you first suggested `eval "$command"` rather than just suggesting to change the quotes to `"`, i.e. `i=5; command="echo $i"; 
$command` which also would have worked, you prefer the `eval` method? personally I find using `bash -c "$command"` to be more reliable - assuming you dont need the command to be executed in current process

Comment: @the_velour_fog, `command="echo $i"; $command` is not the same thing. That's expanding `$i` into the value of `$command` and then apply split+glob to `$command`. That wouldn't work if `$IFS` was modified, that wouldn't work for `command='cmd1; cmd2'`, etc. I can't see the point of using `bash -c "$command"` unless you do want that command to run in a separate `bash` instance. Here that wouldn't work unless you _exported_ `$i`.

Comment: ah ok, after re-reading my comment, I didnt explain very well,  I meant I find  `bash -c "$command"` more reliable than `$command` for the reasons you mentioned. the way I would use the commands is  `bash -c "$command"` when you need to run as a separate instance, e.g. `sudo -u $SUDO_USER bash -c "$command"` , `eval "$command"` when you want to run in - and affect - the current process .

Comment: the suggestion to use a function instead was a huge help. thanks

Comment: But if `$command` has the following value: `VAR1=foo VAR2=Lo23>-f`, then `echo $VAR2` displays `Lo23`. Any fix to that?

Comment: @payne `>` is a redirection operator in the syntax of the shell, so you'd need it to be quoted if you want it to be part of the string that is assigned to the `VAR2` variable: `$command` should contain `VAR1=foo VAR2='Lo23>-f'` for instance.