# I want echo the value in a1,a2,a3. But my code is printing only a1,a2 and a3 not the value stored inside them

Tags: shell, variable, variable-substitution

```
a1="one"
a2="two"
a3="three"
for ((i=1;i<=3;i=i+1)); do
     echo $a$i
done
```

I have already tried following

1. `echo ${a$i}`
2. `echo $((ai))`
3. `echo ${a}${i}`
4. `c=$(echo a$i)`

But none gave the right answer.

Answer (score 5):

That `((i=1;i<=3;i=i+1))` is ksh93 syntax (now also supported by `bash` and `zsh` (though you need blanks in between `for` and `((` in `zsh`)).

In `ksh93` and in recent versions of `bash` (4.3, 2014 or above), you can do:

```
a1="one"
a2="two"
a3="three"
for ((i=1;i<=3;i=i+1));do
    typeset -n name="a$i"
    printf '%s\n' "$name"
done
```

In `zsh`, you can use variable indirection syntax: `${(e)code}` (since May 1996), `${(P)name}` (since 1999)

```
a1="one"
a2="two"
a3="three"
for ((i=1;i<=3;i=i+1));do
    name=a$i
    printf '%s\n' "${(P)name}"
    # or
    code="\$a$i"
    printf '%s\n' "${(e)code}"
    # or combined:
    printf '%s\n' "${(e):-\$a$i}" "${(P)${:-a$i}}"
done
```

`bash` also added its own variable indirection feature, but using a different syntax (in 2.0 in December 1996), and one that means almost the opposite of that of ksh93:

```
a1="one"
a2="two"
a3="three"
for ((i=1;i<=3;i=i+1));do
    name=a$i
    printf '%s\n' "${!name}"
done
```

With any POSIX shell, (including but not limited to ksh93, bash or zsh), you can always do:

```
a1="one"
a2="two"
a3="three"
i=1; while [ "$i" -le 3 ]; do
    name=a$i
    eval "value=\${$name}"
    printf '%s\n' "$value"
    i=$((i + 1))
done
```

Answer (score 3):

In bash, if you have a variable containing the name of the variable you want, you can use indirection to access it:

```
a1="one"
a2="two"
a3="three"
for((i=1;i<=3;i=i+1));do
    name="a$i"
    printf '%s\n' "${!name}"
done
```

if you use `${...}` to expand a parameter, and the first character is `!` then the rest is treated as the name of parameter that itself contains the name of the parameter you want to access.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Bash, the easiest way to accomplish the same thing is to use an array:

```
a[1]="one"
a[2]="two"
a[3]="three"

for ((i=1; i<=3; i=i+1)); do
    echo "${a[$i]}"
done
```

You can also loop over the array:

```
for value in "${a[@]}"; do
     echo "$value"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If one must go down this route, in `bash` the following works. The idea is to use `eval`:

```
#!/bin/bash

a1="one"
a2="two"
a3="three"

for ((i=1;i<=3;i=i+1)); do
  var="a${i}"
  eval out=\$${var}
  echo $out
done
```

Output:

> one
>   two
>   three

The `eval` approach allows for obtaining the value of a referenced variable. So once we have the variable name itself (above, in `var` as "a${i}" which will be a1, a2, etc), then it is possible to obtain the value of the variable through the `eval` built-in.

There is some discussion here: [What is the "eval" command in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23111/what-is-the-eval-command-in-bash)