# Execute python file from shell script based on the cat/awk output

Tags: shell-script, shell

I'm executing a python file based on the output from the `cat`/`awk` output. 
Say I have a file something like

`samp.txt`:

```
test.py test.conf
dev.py dev.conf
```

Now I have a small shell script, which `cat`s the `samp.txt` file and triggers the Python script.

`samp.sh`:

```
OLDIFS=$IFS; IFS=$'\n';for file in $(cat samp.txt) ;
do
    text="$file -c $1 -s $2 -t $3"
    out=`python $text`

done
```

When I run the shell script, it says

```
python: can't open file 'test.py test.conf' : [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

The problem is because of the single quotes. Need some suggestions to get over it.

Comment: Do you specify the absolute path to test.py?

Comment: Yes , i cd into the directory and then execute it

Comment: Do you have both test.py and test.conf in the name quotes? For example: `python ‘test.py test.conf’`. In this case, python would treat that as one argument. You’d need to make sure there are in their own quotes.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is not due to any single quotes (I'm assuming you're referring to the single quotes displayed in the error output; these are just Python's way of displaying the error) but to the fact that you rely on the shell to split `$text` into separate words on spaces.  At the same time, you have removed the space character from the `IFS` variable before your loop, which means that the shell won't do that splitting correctly.

The correct solution is *not* to get the shell to split `$text` on spaces, as that would still also invoke filename globbing on the generated words.  Since `$text` contains `$1`, `$2` and `$3`, these values would also be split on spaces etc. when `$text` is split.

Instead of relying on the shell to split the `$text` variable correctly, read the two words on each line of `samp.txt` in a `while` loop:

```
while read -r script config; do
    out=$( python "$script" "$config" -c "$1" -s "$2" -t "$3" )
done <samp.txt
```

If you want to use a separate variable for your arguments, and if you're using e.g. `bash` or another shell that has named arrays:

```
args=( -c "$1" -s "$2" -t "$3" )
while read -r script config; do
    out=$( python "$script" "$config" "${args[@]}" )
done <samp.txt
```

Using an array for the arguments instead of a text string allows the argument to be properly delimited within the array.  The expansion of `"${args[@]}"` would be the separate elements of that array with each element properly quoted.  This means that e.g. `$1`, `$2` and `$3` could contain spaces etc. without any issues.

In a POSIX (`/bin/sh`) script, assuming you can safely discard the positional parameters from `$4` onwards:

```
set -- -c "$1" -s "$2" -t "$3"
while read -r script config; do
    out=$( python "$script" "$config" "$@" )
done <samp.txt
```

Comment: On a different note, most POSIX compatible shells do implement [eval](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/23117/19575)

Comment: @Bananguin Yes they do. But it's difficult to use correctly and safely, especially if user-supplied data is involved. I have never had to use `eval` in my own scripts.  Here, for example, `eval` is definitely not needed.

Comment: +1 for the use of a bash array to delimit array components properly. I had to try it to convince myself that it works as intended. Still learning and my hat is off to you, even though as I already said on SE, I tend to shy away from bashisms.  Go POSIX instead !