# Renaming environment variables by changing variable name prefix

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed, environment-variables

I have a few environment variables. There are multiple such values I want to convert dynamically.

Env variable: I'm getting this env variable using `printenv | grep proj_env_repo` ( doing like `printenv | grep $value`).

so the value is `proj_env_repo`

and my results are

```
proj_env_repo_db_username=username
```

I want to convert it to `TF_ENV_db_username=username`

Can someone help me with it? I'm looking for a function in bash script.

Comment: Do you have many variables with the same name prefix?

Comment: There will be two variables with the same prefix for each proj

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using variable name prefix matching and variable indirection in `bash`:

```bash
proj_env_repo_db_username=username
proj_env_repo_db_host=host
proj_env_repo_db_port=port

for variable in "${!proj_env_repo@}"; do
    export "TF_ENV${variable#proj_env_repo}"="${!variable}"
done
```

The loop uses `"${!proj_env_repo@}"` to generate a list of variable names that share the name prefix `proj_env_repo`.  In each iteration `$variable` will be the name of one of these variables.

Inside the loop, `export` is used to create a new environment variable by stripping off the `proj_env_repo` prefix and replacing it with the string `TF_ENV`.  The value for the new environment variable is had using the variable indirection `${!variable}`, i.e. the value of the variable whose name is stored in `$variable`.

To additionally unset the original variable, use `unset "$variable"` after `export`, before the end of the loop.

Test running this with tracing turned on:

```
$ bash -x script.sh
+ proj_env_repo_db_username=username
+ proj_env_repo_db_host=host
+ proj_env_repo_db_port=port
+ for variable in "${!proj_env_repo@}"
+ export TF_ENV_db_host=host
+ TF_ENV_db_host=host
+ for variable in "${!proj_env_repo@}"
+ export TF_ENV_db_port=port
+ TF_ENV_db_port=port
+ for variable in "${!proj_env_repo@}"
+ export TF_ENV_db_username=username
+ TF_ENV_db_username=username
```

As a function taking the old name prefix as its 1st argument and the new prefix as its 2nd argument:

```bash
rename_var () {
    # Make sure arguments are valid as variable name prefixes
    if ! [[ $1 =~ ^[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*$ ]] ||
       ! [[ $2 =~ ^[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*$ ]]
    then
        echo 'bad variable name prefix' >&2
        return 1
    fi

    eval 'for variable in "${!'"$1"'@}"; do
              export "'"$2"'${variable#'"$1"'}"="${!variable}"
          done'
}
```

We resort to using `eval` over the loop here since `bash` does not support the syntax `${!$1@}`.  The function constructs the appropriate shell code (as a string) for renaming the variables according to the values of `$1` and `$2` (the 1st and 2nd argument given to the function), and then uses `eval` to execute this shell code.

You would use this function as

```sh
rename_var project_env_repo TF_ENV
```

... or, using variables,

```sh
rename_var "$old_variable_prefix" "$new_variable_prefix"
```

Note: When doing things like these (using `eval` on user input), you *must* test that the code that you evaluate is valid and that it is what you expect it to be.  In this case this mean validating `$1` and `$2` as valid variable name prefixes.  Otherwise at least quotes and `}` will cause syntax errors in the `eval`, and there is a possibility of command injection.

---

Note: This is the first time (I think) that I've ever *had* to use [`eval`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23111/what-is-the-eval-command-in-bash).  I would never put myself in the position of having to use the above code though, but I don't know the background story to the question, obviously, so that's not real criticism of the question (which is an interesting one in itself).

Related (on the Software Engineering site):

- [Why are eval-like features considered evil, in contrast to other possibly harmful features?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/311507)

Comment: what does `#proj_env_repo` do? what if i need to pass as a variable like $value? would it take that?

Comment: @swat `${something#prefix}` removes the string `prefix` from the beginning of the value of `$something`. So `${variable#proj_env_repo}` removes the string `proj_env_repo` from beginning of the value `$variable` (which is the name of one of those variables whose name starts with `proj_env_repo`).  For you second follow up question, see the function towards the second half of my answer.

Comment: Example code doesn't work in bash 5.0+.

Answer (score 3):

```
while IFS='=' read -r name value; do
    new_name="TF_ENV${name#proj_env_repo}"
    export "$new_name=$value"
    unset "$name"
done < <( printenv | grep proj_env_repo )
```

The secret ingredients here:

- [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)
- `IFS='=' read -r name value` -- uses the = sign to split the incoming line into the component parts.
- using a [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) so the while loop runs in the current shell.

Comment: why its not working for me, `printenv | grep $new_value | while IFS='=' read -r name value; do   new_name="TF_ENV${name#$new_value}";   export "$new_name=$value"; done` where $new_value=proj_env_repo

Comment: @Kusalananda, d'oh! I'll fix.

Comment: @Swat, please try my edited answer.

Comment: Will there be issues with variables holding newlines?

Answer (score 1):

```
for v in `printenv | grep proj_env_repo`
do
    eval `echo "$v=\$$v" | sed -e 's/proj_env_repo/TF_ENV/'`
    unset $v
done
```

The `echo` prints:

```
proj_env_repo_db_username=$proj_env_repo_db_username
```

The `sed` converts the first instance of `proj_env_repo` with `TF_ENV`.

```
TF_ENV_db_username=$proj_env_repo_db_username
```

The `eval` evaluates that statement.

The `unset` makes sure the old  variable gets deleted.

Comment: Will there be issues with variables holding newlines or other whitespace? E.g. `proj_env_repo_db_string=$'hello\nworld'`

Comment: Note that `$v` is both the name and the value, so you can't `unset` it, nor can you use it as an identifier.